# Solve simplexml_load_string() using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, soap

After numerous attempts still no success, trying to access this 'http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl , providing the username and password and then gathering the xml feedback. This code :

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl');
 $result = $client->getVehicleDetails('spwf87','hk8*9jd'); 
 echo('<pre>'.$result.'</pre>');
```

Dumps the entire text field, want it of course cleaned up as the page source states :

```
<pre><![CDATA[<VEHICLEDETAILS><VEHICLE><ID....
```

etc, so tried using:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl');

$result = $client->getVehicleDetails('pass','user');
 
$content = simplexml_load_string($result, null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$content = simplexml_load_string($content->pre);
$json = json_encode($content);
$content = json_decode($json,TRUE);
var_dump($content);
```

But still get the error of

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in index.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <![CDATA[<VEHICLEDETAILS><VEHICLE><ID>5002386176</ID><VIN>AHTHA3CD503427515</VIN in index.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in index.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in index.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <![CDATA[<VEHICLEDETAILS><VEHICLE><ID>5002386176</ID><VIN>AHTHA3CD503427515</VIN in index.php on line 24

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in index.php on line 24
bool(false)
```

At my wits end, have to present all the data from the source.

Comment: Is the xml document valid ? I think the DomDocument class and it's validate() method provide that information

Comment: You've just posted your userid and password. You'll want to reset that immediately.

Comment: Provided them so anyone can test it safely. Thanks for the spot!

Comment: Got no DTD found using the validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml parser is choking on ampersands that aren't correct entities `&` -> `&amp;`

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl'); 
$result = $client->getVehicleDetails('spwf87','hk8*9jd');
//print_r($result);
$content = substr($result, strlen('<![CDATA['), -3);
$content=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $content);
$content =  simplexml_load_string($content, 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
foreach ($content->VEHICLE as $vehicle_props) {
    echo "\n\n ---------------------";
    foreach ($vehicle_props as $prop_name => $prop_value) {
        if ($prop_name == "EXTRAS")  $prop_value=implode("\n  - ", explode(",", $prop_value));
        echo "\n" . ucwords(strtolower($prop_name)) .": " . $prop_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element nameindex.php on line 40
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <![CDATA[<VEHICLEDETAILS><VEHICLE><ID>5002386176</ID><VIN>AHTHA3CD503427515</VIN in index.php on line 40
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in index.php on line 40
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in index.php on line 40
W: Attempt to read property "VEHICLEDETAILS" on bool in index.php on line 41
W Attempt to read property "VEHICLE" on null index.php on line 41
NULL

Comment: can you post the whole XML or link to a codepen that has it?  There is an invalid element name in there or something odd

Comment: https://codepen.io/RawalD/pen/PopBGym , is this alright ?

Comment: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ didnt raise any errors

Comment: $vehicle = $content->VEHICLEDETAILS->VEHICLE; on this the linter states expected object received string maybe this ?

Comment: $content returns False on a simple if/else check

Comment: Apparently if a SOAP envelope is present SimpleXML cant parse it

Comment: Same error as the barrage of Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element nameindex.php on line 40... What a frustrating one

Comment: $client = new SoapClient('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl');
$result = $client->getVehicleDetails('spwf87','hk8*9jd'); , incase you'd like to see

Comment: That's working brilliantly! Thank you so much! Is there any way to render everything about every vehicle ? Used the <prev></prev> tag but can only print that specific one, while loop completely hung it of course. Any way I can print the properties out neatly of all received results ? Thank you so much for all the time!

Comment: Updated answer and preview link